# C#: Populate Combobox with single column in CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a csv file with multiple columns, "PROJECT NAME", "PROJECT BUILD". I am trying to populate comobobox with Project Name column only.

Project name column might have multiple repeated names but repeated names should only appear once in combobox as an option to select. For example: in column 1, under "Project Name", Toyota is listed 4 times and Honda is listed 8 Times. Combobox will have 2 things, Toyota and Honda.

Here is my code so far:

// Wehn Form Loads___________________________________________________________________________________________________

```
    public void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        string column = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] eachColumn = column.Split(',');

        foreach (string s in eachColumn)
        {
            
            Project_Name_Combobox.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

The current code gets me the entire csv content (row and column) separated by "," listed under combo box. :(. Any help is apricated.

Comment: You split the 'row' into 'columns' then loop thru and add everything.  If you only want one column, save them all to a collection/array;. then if you want just the unique ones, research `.Distinct` to get just that.  When the preprocessing is complete, **then** add them to the combo

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate out the rows and columns from csv and store whatever you need separately like below.

```
  public void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        List<string> ProjectNames = new List<string>();
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var EachRow = sr.ReadLine();
            var Columns= EachRow.Split(',');
            if(lineNumber != 1){
            ProjectNames.Add(Columns[0]);           
            }
             lineNumber++;                
        }
       ProjectNames = ProjectNames.Distinct().ToList();
       foreach(var projectName in ProjectNames){
         Project_Name_Combobox.Items.Add(projectName);
       }                            
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sabha, thank you for you help. I have a question, why am I getting an error under reader.Readline();

Comment: It should be `sr.ReadLine();`, it's a type-o.

Comment: It's my bad. Replace the reader.ReadLine() with sr.ReadLine()

Comment: you don't have to pass anything. It will only return the unique values from your project names

Comment: My combobox shows this line only "System.Linq.Enumerable+<DisticntIterator>d_64'1[System.String]

Comment: The column "ProjcetName" is populated but its not listed in my Combobox

Comment: @Jabir please check the above edited code

Comment: @SabhaKandula, you rock. thank you. That did it. Is there a way I can upvote your profile? I am a bit new to Stack :).

Comment: also, its picking up the header of column also, is there a way to skip row one?

Comment: @Jabir I have edited the code to exclude the header. Please upvote and mark as answer if possible

Comment: @SabhaKandula, Thank you very much. Thank you for you help. I really appreciate you working this out for me.